# How to add JMS properties via Spring Integration using ws:outbound-gateway (JMS transport)

Tags: spring-integration

I have a **ws:outbound-gateway** in place pointing to a **org.springframework.ws.transport.jms.JmsMessageSender** class in order to push a Soap message into the queue.

The output message has been generated okay and published into the queue normally with the following JMS properties on it: **SOAPJMS_soapAction, SOAPJMS_contentLength, SOAPJMS_contentType, etc**.

My question is: how can I add a custom JMS property as part of the JMS properties generated by default? Is this possible? I'm using Spring Integration **4.3.5.RELEASE**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JmsMessageSender` can be supplied with the `MessagePostProcessor`.

The you can supply any desired JMS property on target `Message`.